# File exist but glide does not show anything

Tags: java, android, android-glide

This is my code:

```
            String mmimg = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+arrPictures.get(0).getPath();
            Log.e("mmimg",mmimg); ///storage/emulated/0/productss/Montearci_products/Bracelets/airplane/Brac - 020.jpg
            File mfile = new File(mmimg);
            Uri muri = Uri.fromFile(mfile);
            if(!mfile.exists()){
                Log.e("oops","oooops"); //it does't show
            }

            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(muri)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(mimg);
```

but my `imageView` doesn't not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

please test this code and reply if solved your problem :

put this instead of the first line :

```
String mmimg = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+arrPictures.get(0).getPath();
```

and I think it is better that you say what kind of data you have in the arrayList.